# Python combinations of list elements with condition

Tags: python

I find source code of `itertools.combinations()` function in python. It looks like this.

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
pool = tuple(iterable)
n = len(pool)
if r > n:
    return
indices = list(range(r))
print(indices)
yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
while True:
    for i in reversed(range(r)):
        if indices[i] != i + n - r:
            break
    else:
        return
    indices[i] += 1
    for j in range(i+1, r):
        indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
    print(indices)
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

I have tuples like this:

```
pairs = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

I need to generate foursomes of all possible combinations, but with condition, that there will be always only two same numbers in list. So in this case this 3 list I want to generate:

```
((0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3))
((0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3))
((0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3))
```

What I realy need is to update code of generation combinations, because in my real app I need to generate 23-nties from 80 tuples. Generation and filtering after it would take a lot of time, thats why I need to catch problem in part of generation.

Comment: Please edit the "23 from 80" requirement into your question.  Also, please provide a slightly larger example to help clarify.

Comment: Do you need a *maximum* 2 of any number, or do you require *exactly* 2?
The latter is harder, but may be faster.

Comment: By *"I have tuples like this"* do you mean like `list(it.combinations(range(n), 2))` for some number `n`? Or can the tuples be any numbers?

Comment: No, in tuple list there are always not same pairs of numbers.

Comment: @Prune Yes, exactly 2.

Comment: Are the numbers in the tuples always in ascending order?  Can you have individual clusters within a group? For isntance, given n=6, can we have `((0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (5, 6), (5, 7), (6, 7))` two disjoint triangles?  When you've edited your question with a complete problem statement and your coding attempt, I'll be happy to give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and then filter the result using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
import itertools as it

pairs = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
result = filter(
    lambda x: max(Counter(it.chain(*x)).values()) < 3,
    it.combinations(pairs, 4)
)
print(list(result))
```

Output:

```
[((0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)),
 ((0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3)),
 ((0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3))]
```

Comment: Yes it is true, but I need to catch this problem not after generation of all possible combinations, but in process of generation combinations.

Comment: @M.Barabas Why? `it.combinations` is a generator and it doesn't really matter where you perform the check, before or after yielding. It probably won't hurt performance, especially since you don't need to rewrite the function.

Comment: Because this question was only example. In my real app I need generate 23-nties from list which contains 80 tuples. In this case it will take long time to generate all possible combinations.